# Query in /var/log/auth.log in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu

I have installed livecricketscore application on Ubuntu 13.04. But it won't work & after that my auth.log file shows

```
"Apr 1 11:50:01 lnode137 CRON[5075]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user cricket by (uid=0)".
```

This is a small part of the /var/log/auth.log file of my system.
Can anyone help me to remove "user cricket by ..." written in this log file?

```
Apr 1 11:50:01 lnode137 CRON[5075]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user cricket by (uid=0)

Apr 1 11:50:02 lnode137 CRON[5075]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user cricket

Apr 1 11:52:24 lnode137 sudo: RADIXLOCAL\ronak.gohel : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/likewise-open/RADIXLOCAL/ronak.gohel ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chmod 777 /var/log/auth.log

Apr 1 11:52:24 lnode137 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by RADIXLOCAL\ronak.gohel(uid=0)

Apr 1 11:52:24 lnode137 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root

Apr 1 11:55:01 lnode137 CRON[5165]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user cricket by (uid=0)

Apr 1 11:55:01 lnode137 CRON[5165]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user cricket

Apr 1 11:55:36 lnode137 sudo: RADIXLOCAL\ronak.gohel : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/likewise-open/RADIXLOCAL/ronak.gohel ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/dmesg -C

Apr 1 11:55:36 lnode137 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by RADIXLOCAL\ronak.gohel(uid=0)

Apr 1 11:55:36 lnode137 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root

Apr 1 11:58:07 lnode137 sudo: RADIXLOCAL\ronak.gohel : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/likewise-open/RADIXLOCAL/ronak.gohel ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-get autoremove cricket

Apr 1 11:58:07 lnode137 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by RADIXLOCAL\ronak.gohel(uid=0)

Apr 1 11:58:47 lnode137 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root

Apr 1 12:00:01 lnode137 CRON[8017]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user cricket by (uid=0)

Apr 1 12:00:01 lnode137 CRON[8017]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user cricket

Apr 1 12:02:08 lnode137 sudo: RADIXLOCAL\ronak.gohel : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/likewise-open/RADIXLOCAL/ronak.gohel ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/gedit /var/log/auth.log.1

Apr 1 12:02:08 lnode137 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by RADIXLOCAL\ronak.gohel(uid=0)

Apr 1 12:04:23 lnode137 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root

Apr 1 12:05:01 lnode137 CRON[8216]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user cricket by (uid=0)

Apr 1 12:05:01 lnode137 CRON[8216]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user cricket

Apr 1 12:10:01 lnode137 CRON[8267]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user cricket by (uid=0)

Apr 1 12:10:01 lnode137 CRON[8267]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user cricket

Apr 1 12:15:01 lnode137 CRON[8307]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user cricket by (uid=0)

Apr 1 12:15:01 lnode137 CRON[8307]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user **cricket**

Apr 1 12:17:01 lnode137 CRON[8329]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user **root** by (uid=0)

Apr 1 12:17:01 lnode137 CRON[8329]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the application has created a new user named cricket and added a cron job that will probably update score using cricket user.

You can remove user by [userdel](http://linux.die.net/man/8/userdel) command.
Also refer [this](https://www.webhostingdiscussion.net/forums/index.php/topic,294.0.html) for guide to remove cron job.